# Consulta para sacar datos con PHP en una BBDD MySQL en base a varios IDs

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito hacer una tabla HTML con datos de una BBDD a partir del nombre de un instituto. Al seleccionar un instituto captura un ID de una tabla de la BBDD. En base a ese ID, va a sacar "x" alumnos... en base a cada ID de los alumnos debe sacar el ID de todas las clases en las que está añadido y a su vez, con ese mismo ID, obtener de otra tabla dentro de esta misma BBDD su número de clase único... Empecé a hacer la función y me arroja datos pero, están mal o incompletos. Cómo hago para realizar una búsqueda tan grande en un único Query? He aquí la función:

```
function checkUser($searchType, $centro) {
                    $hostname = '127.0.0.1';
                    $username = 'root';
                    $password = '';
                    $database = 'bbdd';
                    $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
                    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');  // Caracteres a UTF8
                    $buscaCentro = explode(' &&& ', $_POST['buscaCentro']);
                    $check = false;

                    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                        echo 'Error de conexión: %s\n' + mysqli_connect_error();
                        exit();

                    }  else {

                        foreach ($buscaCentro as $centro) {
                            $resultCentro = '';
                            $centroId = '';

                            // Buscamos el centro
                            if ($searchType == 'buscaCentro') {
                                $resultCentro = $mysqli->query(
                                    "SELECT * FROM `colegios` WHERE `name` LIKE '$centro'"
                                );
                            }

                            // Capturamos resultados del centro
                            if (mysqli_num_rows($resultCentro) > 0) {
                                while ($row = $resultCentro->fetch_row()) {
                                    $centroId = $row[0];
                                }
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }

                            $resultadoAlumno = '';

                            if ($centroId != '') {
                                $resultadoAlumno = $mysqli->query(
                                    "SELECT * FROM `estudiantes` WHERE `estudiantes_colegios_id` LIKE '$centroId'"
                                );
                            }
                            $auxVar = '';
                            // Capturamos resultados de los alumnos
                            if (mysqli_num_rows($resultadoAlumno) > 0) {
                                while ($row = $resultadoAlumno->fetch_row()) {

                                    $auxAl = $row[0];

                                    $resultadoclases = '';

                                    $resultadoclases = $mysqli->query(
                                        "SELECT * FROM `estudiantes_clases` WHERE `estudiantes_clases_estudiante_id` LIKE '$auxAl'"
                                    );

                                    $resultadosLicencias = $mysqli->query(
                                        "SELECT * FROM `datos_estudiantes` WHERE `estudiante_id` LIKE '$auxAl'"
                                    );


                                    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultadosLicencias) > 0) { 
                                        while ($rowLi = $resultadosLicencias->fetch_row()) {
                                            $auxVar = $rowLi[1];
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultadoclases) > 0) {
                                        while ($rowCt = $resultadoclases->fetch_row()) {
                                            if ($rowCt[1] != 0) {
                                                $nombreClases = '';
                                                $nombreClase = $rowCt[1];
                                                $nombreClases = $mysqli->query(
                                                    "SELECT * FROM `estudiantes_clases` WHERE `clase_id` LIKE '$nombreClase'"
                                                );
                                                echo '<tr>';
                                                // Cpaturamos resultados del centro
                                                if (mysqli_num_rows($nombreClases) > 0) {
                                                    while ($fila = $nombreClases->fetch_row()) {
                                                        if ($fila[1] !='') {
                                                            echo '<td>'.$fila[1].'</td>';
                                                            echo '<td>'.$auxVar.'</td>';
                                                            echo '<td>'.$fila[1].'</td>';
                                                        }

                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    return false;
                                                }
                                                echo '<tr>';
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }

                            echo '</table>';

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: No lanza error como tal la aplicación. El error lo veo en la consulta de la base de datos que si voy a buscar esos resultados manualmente, hay más que esta aplicación ignora. ¿Cómo hago para hacer una consulta única y me arroje lo que necesito?

Comment: Si vas a tener un Combobox con los nombres de los institutos, tu consulta no debería tener LIKE sino = '$centro'. De esta manera los resultados de la búsqueda son más exactos.

Comment: ¿Para todas las consultas? ¿Podrías ponerme un ejemplo?

Comment: Si, para todas. "SELECT * FROM `estudiantes` WHERE `estudiantes_colegios_id` = '$centroId'". "SELECT * FROM `colegios` WHERE `name` = '$centro'"

Comment: Voy a probar a ver qué tal. Thanks!

Comment: Listo, todo ok! Es la respuesta correcta :)